# What is the correct way to select one of many child elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small part of my new React app which contains a block of text, `AllLines`, split into line-by-line components called `Line`. I want to make it work so that when one line is clicked, it will be selected and editable and all other lines will appear as `<p>` elements. How can I best manage the state here such that only one of the lines is selected at any given time? The part I am struggling with is determining which `Line` element has been clicked in a way that the parent can change its state.

I know ways that I can make this work, but I'm relatively new to React and trying to get my head into 'thinking in React' by doing things properly so I'm keen to find out what is the best practice in this situation.

```
class AllLines extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedLine: 0,
        lines: []
    };

    handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("click");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                {
                    this.state.lines.map((subtitle, index) => {
                        if (index === this.state.selectedLine) {
                            return (
                                <div id={"text-line-" + index}>
                                    <TranscriptionLine
                                        lineContent={subtitle.text}
                                        selected={true}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        return (
                            <div id={"text-line-" + index}>
                                <Line
                                    lineContent={subtitle.text}
                                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Line extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.selected === true) {
            return (
                <input type="text" value={this.props.lineContent} />
            )
        }
        return (
            <p id={} onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.lineContent}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: even though you've got accepted answer already, from your following comment it appears to me that your problem is not solved entirely yet. If your problem still persists and you wont' mind to consider other options, you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189836/11299053) followed by live-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'Thinking in React'* you would want to give up your habit to grab DOM elements by their unique `id` ;)

From what I see, there're few parts missing from your codebase:

- smart click handler that will keep only one line selected at a time
- edit line handler that will stick to the callback that will modify line contents within parent state
- preferably two separate components for the line capable of editing and line being actually edited as those behave in a different way and appear as different DOM elements

To wrap up the above, I'd slightly *rephrase* your code into the following:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM
      
const linesData = Array.from(
        {length:10},
        (_,i) => `There goes the line number ${i}`
      )      
      
class Line extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <p onClick={this.props.onSelect}>{this.props.lineContent}</p>
    )
  }
}

class TranscriptionLine extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      content: this.props.lineContent
    }
    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this)
  }
  
  onEdit(value){
    this.setState({content:value})
    this.props.pushEditUp(value, this.props.lineIndex)
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <input
        style={{width:200}}
        value={this.state.content} 
        onChange={({target:{value}}) => this.onEdit(value)} 
      />
    )
  }
}

class AllLines extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        selectedLine: null,
        lines: this.props.lines
      }
      this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
      this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this)
    }
    
    handleSelect(idx){
      this.setState({selectedLine:idx})
    }
    
    handleEdit(newLineValue, lineIdx){
      const linesShallowCopy = [...this.state.lines]
      linesShallowCopy.splice(lineIdx,1,newLineValue)
      this.setState({
        lines: linesShallowCopy
      })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.lines.map((text, index) => {
                        if(index === this.state.selectedLine) {
                            return (
                                    <TranscriptionLine
                                        lineContent={text}
                                        lineIndex={index}
                                        pushEditUp={this.handleEdit}
                                    />
                            )
                        }
                        else
                            return (
                                    <Line
                                        lineContent={text}
                                        lineIndex={index}
                                        onSelect={() => this.handleSelect(index)}
                                    />
                            )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render (
  <AllLines lines={linesData} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Yevgen! I have changed this to the accepted answer since this is closer to what I was looking for. The solution I have reached is much more similar to yours, although my edit handler is on the onBlur event rather than onChange, and I have left the Line as a single component for now. I have removed the need for ids on any of the elements, which feels like a more React way of doing things.

Comment: There're pros and cons of using either `onBlur` or `onChange`, surely it's up to you to balance between those. As for single component or multiple, you may eventually come to the point where you're going to need to split them for the sake of easier maintenance, my suggestion was to do that earlier. However, glad my answer did help, thanks for picking this one.

Comment: You're right, I've found for this use-case onBlur is more suitable, however, I had it working with onChange as you described as

Answer (score 2):

In your case, there is no really simpler way. State of current `selected` `Line` is "above" line collection (parent), which is correct (for case where siblings need to know).

However, you could simplify your code *a lot*:

```
<Container>
{this.state.lines.map((subtitle, index) => (
    <div id={"text-line-" + index}>
        <Line
            handleClick={this.handleClick}
            lineContent={subtitle.text}
            selected={index === this.state.selectedLine}
        />
    </div>
))}
</Container>
```

and for `Line` component, it is good practice to use functional component, since it is stateless and even doesn't use any lifecycle method.

Edit: Added missing close bracket

Comment: Thank you! I suppose the only other question I have would be about how to retrieve the id of which element has been clicked. At the moment that is on the div id, is there any way (or reason) that this could be on the child element? 

Thanks for the suggestion on the simplification as well. I'd planned on doing that but hadn't got round to it just yet.

Comment: Your `handleClick` could return a function with current `id` as closure: `handleClick = (id) => (event) => this.setState({ ... selectedLine: id}`